# Rotating screen on Fedora

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, fedora

I run Fedora 19 under KDE and would want to configure two 27" screens rotated 90 degrees. My problem is that while I can go to:

System Settings -> Display and Monitor

and rotate them 90 degrees, this setting does not work in the login screen. Therefore, my desktop is correctly rotated, but in the login screen I have to bend sideways to look at the screen.

A plus would also be a way to get the output rotated in the text mode console. I'm sure that this won't be doable for the kernel boot output, but once login terminals are loaded I should be able to instruct the framebuffer somehow to rotate the output.

Comment: Which display manager are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what login manager Fedora 19 uses by default - you haven't said which you happen to be using, if not the default. Regardless, I know that the LightDM display manager (Ubuntu's current default) is usable in Fedora, so here is an answer for LightDM. Other login managers should have something equivalent.

*With that in mind...*

There should be a directory called `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` which is where custom configurations can be stored. You can create a new file in that directory (you'll need to be root) called `20-startup-script.conf`:

```
[SeatDefaults]
display-setup-script=/usr/local/bin/rotate-screen
```

In the script `/usr/local/bin/rotate-screen`, you can write a script which rotates the screen, and LightDM will run this script before it displays the login screen. In order to rotate the screen, you'll need to use a tool called `xrandr`.

You'll have to play around with `xrandr` on the command line to get an idea of what options you should be using, but you can do something like this:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: ...
LVDS1 connected ...
    1366x768 ...
    ...
VGA1 disconnected ...
....
```

Names like `LVDS1` and `VGA1` are *output names*, and you'll want to keep these in mind. You can figure out which display name corresponds to the monitor you want to rotate by doing the following:

```
$ xrandr --output LVDS1 --rotate left
```

If the screen rotates, then you've found the right display name (in this case, LVDS1).

You can then write the following script into `/usr/local/bin/rotate-screen` (requires root access):

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output LVSD1 --rotate left
```

You can then `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rotate-screen` (also requires root), and then log out. If you did it correctly, the login screen should be rotated, and LightDM will rotate the screen before every login.